# laravel 5 pdf create, download & print

Tags: laravel-5, pdf-generation

I have this kind of blade view right now to show customer's invoice

[image]

I saw most of the sites they are creating a pdf and show it in the browser. then I think browser allows to print and dowload and also zoom in/out. exactly like this 
[image]

So any hint or way to do that easily. I have tried DomPDF but it won't let me do complex styles. I want it like open pdf in browser and do print and download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DomPDF still doesn't support many new CSS features. So I am using [laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy). You just have to create a html page using any css framework or as per your desire. Then just load it using snappy and it will create a pdf of that page. It is basically takes a snapshot of `url` or `html` page and creates a PDF. So your pdf and html page will look exactly same.

Now For downloading PDF you can use

```
 return Response::download($filepath);
```

You can open that PDF in another tab so that it will show more option depending upon the browser.

Answer (score 3):

using laravel 5.4 on a 32 bit ubuntu.

add these three lines to composer.json

```
"barryvdh/laravel-snappy": ">=0.4.0",
"h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "0.12.x",
"h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-i386": "0.12.x"
```

64-bit systems

```
"barryvdh/laravel-snappy": ">=0.4.0",
"h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
"h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "0.12.x",
```

from your terminal , navigate to your laravel folder and type

> composer update

In config/app add these two lines under 'aliases'

> 'PDF' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class,
>
> 'SnappyImage' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage::class,

in your terminal type

> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider"

go to config/snappy and change your binary path for 'pdf' array to this

> 'binary'    =>  base_path('/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386'),

and 'image' array to this:

> 'binary'    =>  base_path('/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-i386/bin/wkhtmltoimage-i386'),

To try it out, in your controller, you can do something like:

```
public function postPDFPrint() {

        $pdf = \App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
        return $pdf->inline();
    }
```

If you would like to print from a view, load the view and pass in the data like you normally would. I would suggest loading a specific 'view' with print-specific CSS for printing to pdf.

```
public function postAdminPrint()
{
        $form = Form::find(1);
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('form.admin-print'['form'=>$form]);
        return $pdf->inline();  
}
```

To Debug "Exit Status Code 127: Something went wrong..." error. First we try to print via command line. Navigate to the root of your laravel installation inside your terminal and type:

```
vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 http://www.google.com test.pdf
```

If it is installed correctly and there are no folder permissions issue then you should see the following lines appearing in your terminal.

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

A print out of google's home page should appear in ur Laravel root directory. Otherwise, it is your folder permissions causing the error.

If the above works then try to change your binary paths that I wrote initially above to:

```
/var/www/html/new/project/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64

/var/www/html/new/project/vendor/h4cc/hkhtmltoimage-amd64/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64
```

"/var/www/html" --> my web folder in apache
"/new/project" --> my laravel directory

How to utilize the facade's options:

```
// Within your controller class
use PDF;

public function YourControllerFunction(Model $model) {

$pdf = PDF::loadView('path.to.your.file',['model'=>$model])
        ->setPaper('a4')
        ->setOptions([
            'header-html'=>"/var/www/html/{your-laravel-install-folder}/resources/views/header.html", // display a image logo on every page header
            'footer-font-size'=>'8',
            'footer-left'=>'Footer Left Text',
            'footer-center'=>'Footer Center Text',
            'footer-right'=>'Footer Right Text']);

            return $pdf->inline();
      }
```

Your "header.html" file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
        </head>   
        <body>      
            <img style="display:block;" height="100" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/{your-dropbox-image-id}?raw=1">
        </body>
    </html>
```

Reference: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy